# How to handle REST API calls in Azure Static web apps

Tags: azure, rest, azure-sql-database, azure-static-web-app

I want to create a Gatsby Azure static web app.

What is the best practice for implementing CRUD operations via REST API connection to an Azure SQL database in different Azure Static web app forms?

Please consider the two different types of tables:

1. 1:1/1:N relationship tables -> for example: Books-Table
2. N:M relationship tables -> for example: Book-Category-Table

Here are my ideas:

**1:1/1:N relationship-table**

```
C(reate) book form: 
   POST (for inserting new book)
R(ead) book(s) form:
   GET (for selecting one or all books)
U(pdate) book form:
   PUT (for updating the selected book)
D(elete) book form:
   DELETE (for deleting the selected book)
```

**N:M relationship table**

```
C(reate) book-category form: 
   POST (for inserting new book-category combinations)
R(ead) book-category form:
   GET (for selecting one or all book-category combinations)    
U(pdate) book-category form:
   DELETE (for deleting all book-category combinations)
   POST (for inserting the updated/new book-category combinations)
D(elete) book-category form:
   DELETE (for deleting the relevant book-category combination)
```

Is there any other function to handle especially updates of N:M relationship table?

Can I send any request which checks which book-category combinations already exists and handles them properly?

I am totally open for different ideas or approaches.

**Addition:**

My main question is: How can I implement the update of a N:M relationsship.
I have a table book (with book_id as primary key) and a table book-category (with surrogate key "book AND category")

For example the book-category-table looks like that:
Book 1 - Category 10
Book 1 - Category 11

Now I want to update the relevant categories via form and REST API call.
Book 1 - Category 10
Book 1 - Category 20

How can I do that?
Do I have to delete all entries for "book = 1" and then insert the new values?
I can not update the book, I have to update the book-category table.

Comment: this is not an Azure-question but a REST basics one. to assign a book to a category you should edit the book (assign it to a category), not the category.

Comment: @user23348508 please share the code u tried

Comment: @sampath: I do not have any code...

Comment: @sampath: what do you mean?

Comment: I will share you rest api url implementation in node js with azure SQL . Convert it in to our requirements like react etc.

Comment: @Sampath Thanks for your suggested help. Do you know when to provide the url implementation?

Comment: will update and provide the rest api url implementation in node js with Azure SQL by today with delay time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below sample code is to  handle REST API calls in Azure Static web apps

The `gatsby-source-rest-api` plugin enables you to fetch data from various REST APIs and use it within your Gatsby application.

The below sample is to fetching data from REST APIs and displaying it on your Gatsby site with data sourced from REST APIs using the `gatsby-source-rest-api` [plugin](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-source-rest-api/).

- Install the `gatsby-source-rest-api` package
  `npm install --save gatsby-source-rest-api`

**gatsby-config.js:**

```
module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    title: "My Gatsby Site",
  },
  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-source-rest-api',
      options: {
        endpoints: [
          // Specify the endpoints from which you want to fetch data
          'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',
          'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users',
          // Add more endpoints if needed
        ],
      },
    },
  ],
}
```

**posts.js:**

```js
// src/pages/posts.js

import React from "react"
import { graphql } from "gatsby"

const PostsPage = ({ data }) => {
  const posts = data.allRestApiPosts.edges

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Posts</h1>
      <ul>
        {posts.map(({ node }) => (
          <li key={node.id}>
            <h2>{node.title}</h2>
            <p>{node.body}</p>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
}

export const query = graphql`
  query {
    allRestApiPosts {
      edges {
        node {
          id
          userId
          title
          body
        }
      }
    }
  }
`

export default PostsPage
```

**seo.js:**

```js
//src\components\seo.js
import * as React from "react"
import { useStaticQuery, graphql } from "gatsby"

function Seo({ description, title, children }) {
  const { site } = useStaticQuery(
    graphql`
      query {
        site {
          siteMetadata {
            title
            description
          }
        }
      }
    `
  )

  const metaDescription = description || site.siteMetadata.description
  const defaultTitle = site.siteMetadata?.title

  return (
    <>
      <title>{defaultTitle ? `${title} | ${defaultTitle}` : title}</title>
      <meta name="description" content={metaDescription} />
      <meta property="og:title" content={title} />
      <meta property="og:description" content={metaDescription} />
      <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
      <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary" />
      <meta name="twitter:title" content={title} />
      <meta name="twitter:description" content={metaDescription} />
      {children}
    </>
  )
}

export default Seo
```

[image]

**Azure Static Web App Output:**
[image]

- Call all your CRUD operations URL via a REST API connection to an Azure SQL database in `gatsby-config.js` and change the logic according to the requirements in Gatsby and deploy to the Azure static web app. Not sure about the functionality to handle updates of N:M relationship table.
- Yes, the functionality of checking book-category combinations is possible.

**Implementing an N:M relationship:**

```sql
-- Books table
CREATE TABLE Books (
    BookID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    Title VARCHAR(100),
    Author VARCHAR(100),
    PublishedYear INT
);

-- Categories table
CREATE TABLE Categories (
    CategoryID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    Name VARCHAR(100)
);

-- BookCategory table
CREATE TABLE BookCategory (
    BookID INT,
    CategoryID INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (BookID, CategoryID),
    FOREIGN KEY (BookID) REFERENCES Books(BookID),
    FOREIGN KEY (CategoryID) REFERENCES Categories(CategoryID)
);
```

```sql
SELECT * FROM BookCategory WHERE BookID = 1;\
```

[image]

```sql
DELETE FROM BookCategory WHERE BookID = 1 AND CategoryID = 10;
```

[image]

```sql
INSERT INTO BookCategory (BookID, CategoryID) VALUES (1, 30);
```

[image]

**Updated:**

Creating a REST API with Node.js and [Express](https://blog.postman.com/how-to-create-a-rest-api-with-node-js-and-express/).

- The code below is an Express.js server that interacts with a SQL Server database. It provides endpoints to retrieve, add, and delete book categories.

**GET Endpoint**:

- `/api/bookcategories`: This endpoint retrieves book categories based on the provided `bookid` query parameter.

**POST Endpoint**:

- `/api/bookcategories`: This endpoint adds a new book category. It expects the `BookID` and `CategoryID` in the request body.

**DELETE Endpoint**:

- `/api/bookcategories`: This endpoint deletes a book category based on the provided `bookid` and `categoryid` query parameters.
- Use this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-nodejs?tabs=windows&pivots=development-environment-vscode) to create a Node.js web app on Azure App Service.

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const sql = require('mssql');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

// SQL Server configuration
const config = {
  server: 'your_server.database.windows.net',
  database: 'your_database',
  user: 'your_username',
  password: 'your_password',
  options: {
    encrypt: true,
    trustServerCertificate: false,
    connectionTimeout: 30000,
    enableArithAbort: true
  }
};

// Middleware
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// GET endpoint to retrieve book categories by BookID
app.get('/api/bookcategories', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const pool = await sql.connect(config);
    const result = await pool.request()
      .input('BookID', sql.Int, req.query.bookid)
      .query('SELECT * FROM BookCategory WHERE BookID = @BookID');
    
    res.json(result.recordset);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Error executing SQL query:', err);
    res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
  }
});

// POST endpoint to add a new book category
app.post('/api/bookcategories', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const pool = await sql.connect(config);
    const result = await pool.request()
      .input('BookID', sql.Int, req.body.BookID)
      .input('CategoryID', sql.Int, req.body.CategoryID)
      .query('INSERT INTO BookCategory (BookID, CategoryID) VALUES (@BookID, @CategoryID)');
    
    res.status(201).send('Book category added successfully');
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Error executing SQL query:', err);
    res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
  }
});

// DELETE endpoint to delete a book category by BookID and CategoryID
app.delete('/api/bookcategories', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const pool = await sql.connect(config);
    const result = await pool.request()
      .input('BookID', sql.Int, req.query.bookid)
      .input('CategoryID', sql.Int, req.query.categoryid)
      .query('DELETE FROM BookCategory WHERE BookID = @BookID AND CategoryID = @CategoryID');
    
    res.status(200).send('Book category deleted successfully');
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Error executing SQL query:', err);
    res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
  }
});

// Start server
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

I followed this [doc](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-azuretools.vscode-azureappservice) to deploy the sample code as an app on Azure.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your explanation :) And how to implement the Update of N:M-Relationsship table via REST-API? Do I first have to delete the categories for the specific book (via Delete-Request) and after that insert the new book-category combinations (via POST-Request) which wer populated in the form? Is there an other way or best practice to handle update of N:M Relationsship table via REST-API (!) with one request?

Comment: Handling updates to an N:M relationship table via REST API can be accomplished by using separate endpoints for updating relationships. For example: `POST /api/book/:bookId/category/:categoryId` to add a relationship between a book and a category; `DELETE /api/book/:bookId/category/:categoryId` to remove a relationship between a book and a category. I updated a sample implementation of a REST API URL in Node.js with Azure SQL.

Comment: Thank you :) So that means that my origin question "How to update N:M relationshsip table" can be answered that I have to use DELETE and POST Request (like I wrote it in my inital idea). It seems there is no other option to do an "update". For a 1:N relationsship table it is easier, because you can use only PUT -> then the API can take the book-id of the reuqest an update the relevant fields, because there is only one row for each book...

Comment: yes, by using separate DELETE and POST requests to remove and add relationships

Comment: Perfect, then I will use it - thank you for your help :)